# Integrating with Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

Has anyone integrated an "Open in Google Docs" in their web app yet? Gmail has this for opening attachments. How about any other sightings of this in a *non-google* web app?

Answer (score 7):

Google Docs does [have an API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/developers_guide_protocol.html) which allows you to search, upload, delete and retrieve documents from the Google Docs list of a specific user.  You could conceivably use this to upload a document from your server and then retrieve the URL of that document (once it is imported), which you can then use to redirect the user.  It wouldn't be *quite* as slick as Gmail's integration since you wouldn't be able to show that fancy "Importing your document..." page, but it might suffice.

As for other sightings, I am not aware of any.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need this functionality for yourself you could download the "[Send to google docs" firefox extension](http://blogs.bnet.com/businesstips/?p=1855). That will add a right-click menu on all document links on the web and allow you to open them in google docs.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give a look to the [Google Documents List Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/developers_guide_dotnet.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is a gdata objective-c implementation for the api access.

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/